# out varchar2 in package.procedure is giving numeric or value error

Tags: oracle, plsql, varchar2

I have a procedure in a package. there is an out variable `p_return_msg VARCHAR2`.

right after the BEGIN I have `p_return_msg := 'Validation successful.'`

this causes
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "ZWR5KFR.PRICING_AUDIT_PKG", line 187
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "ZWR5KFR.PRICING_AUDIT_PKG", line 134
ORA-06512: at line 1

line 134 is that line and 187 is in the exception section where I'm trying to assign something to it again.  `p_return_msg := 'Validation failed: '`

if I change the line to `p_return_msg := '';` that works until at any point I try to assign anything to it then I get the error again.

I've tried using a temp var and just assign that to it, but same error. Nothing I've tried or could find online seems to help.

EDIT: I think I figured it out. The person calling my procedure doesn't have the variable in C# set up properly to accept a value. They have not confirmed the code I sent them to get the variable properly.

```
var pReturnMsg = new OracleParameter("p_return_msg", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 4000) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the package to blame, but variable that **accepts** procedure's OUT parameter's value.

Sample procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (p_return_msg out varchar2) is
  2  begin
  3    p_return_msg := 'Validation successful.';
  4  end;
  5  /

Procedure created.
```

See `l_msg`'s declaration; 5 characters is just too short!

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_msg varchar2(5);   --> too short!
  3  begin
  4    p_test(l_msg);
  5    dbms_output.put_line(l_msg);
  6  end;
  7  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.P_TEST", line 3
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

But, if we enlarge it, everything is OK:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_msg varchar2(200);   --> long enough
  3  begin
  4    p_test(l_msg);
  5    dbms_output.put_line(l_msg);
  6  end;
  7  /
Validation successful.

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: yep, I think this is exactly it. I supplied the person with some code to make sure they are accepting the output properly. Thanks for your time!